# Flash removeChild after few seconds

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, removechild, addchild

I'm new on Flash, i don't know if it possible, but i'm adding a random movieclip to the stage, using addChild, and i need to remove them after 10 seconds...how can i do this using removeChild?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use the default function from flash library

```
setTimeOut()
```

[More Info](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setTimeout%28%29).

And at the end it would be looking like this:

```
setTimeOut ( removeClip, 2000, clip );

function removeClip ( clip : DisplayObject ) : void
{
    removeChild ( clip );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Timer class. Also the [TweenLite library](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) has a nice function called TweenLite.delayedCall(secondsDelay, functionToCall)